# Connecting thread signal to MainWindow

Tags: python, multithreading, signals-slots

I have two classes. One is the mainWindow class and the other is a thread which will update a progress bar, among other things.

To update the progressBar I am using a signal/slot structure like this: (I show relevant code):

```
import threading
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, Qt


class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    mySignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int)    

    def __init__(self,*args):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

class Form1(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    ...
    ...
    @pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def updateProgress(self, arg1, arg2):
        print "TEST Argument1: ", arg1
        print "TEST Argument2: ", arg2


    def my_function(self):
        mt = MyThread(*args)
        mt.mySignal .connect(self.updateProgress)
        mt.start()
```

And I am getting this that I am not sure to understand:

```
    mt.mySignal .connect(self.updateProgress)
TypeError: pyqtSignal must be bound to a QObject, not 'MyThread'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inherit from *QThread*, not python Thread. Otherwise the QObject-Thread-ownership which is crucial for the signal/slots to work across thread boundaries can't work it's magic.

Comment: It worked perfect, thanks....so amazing how such an small change in the code makes the difference....It actually went from crashing to work just by changing a couple of lines